# virtual dom and real dom issue while changing state

Tags: reactjs, virtual-dom

i am calling console.log just below the setState but it showing my blank array even state has been changed.

```
let text = reminderText;
let data = [...this.state.reminderText]
data.push(text);
this.setState({reminderText:data})
console.log(this.state.reminderText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `setState()` is [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). That means, when your console log is executed, the state is not updated yet.

If you want to print the updated state, use the callback function as shown below.

```
this.setState(
    {reminderText:data},
    () => console.log(this.state.reminderText)
)
```

React will invoke the callback function soon after the asynchronous state  update is complete.